# I am trying to add elements to object using usestate in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I am trying to add a new fields in the useState hook

```
// prevstate  
let [currentdata, setcurrentdata] = useState({
   id:'',
   name:''
  })
```

I try to add new fields in the object like that

```
   setcurrentdata(currentdata => ({
            ...currentdata,
            q: quantity,
          }))
```

but it did not add new fields

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Can't you just change the code for that initial object?

Comment: That's not really how the `useState` hook is (supposed to be) used. Either use a class component, and then you can have as many values in state as you like, with the universal `setState` function to update any or all of them at the same time, or you use `useState`, with one declaration for _each_ state value your component needs. So in this case you'd have five pairs of value/updatefunction, with separate sets for for `id`, `name`, etc.

Comment: *"but it did not add new fields"* - How are you observing this?  Can you provide a [mcve] to demonstrate?

Comment: Where is `currentData` coming from, and what is `quantity`? There's a lot missing from your question that doesn't help us debug the code. Can you provide a [mcve] using the snippet function `[<>]` in the edit panel. You can create [a React one like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: @AirUniversity: For what it's worth, the code shown [demonstrably works](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-lamport-k6l1r5?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: I am trying to add elements to object using usestate

Comment: @AirUniversity: And in what way does that not work as expected?  Read the comments in this thread so far.  (1) The code you've shown has been clearly demonstrated to work as expected.  (2) You are encouraged to provide an example which doesn't work as expected in some way, and describe the specific problem you are observing in that example.  We can't help with a problem that doesn't exist in the code you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet below may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective.

NOTE: I personally dislike the idea of using useState in conjunction with such objects & prefer multiple simpler useState on each variable instead.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const {useState} = React;

const MyFunction = () => {
  const [badStateObj, setBadStateObj] = useState({
    id: '',
    name: ''
  });
  const clickHandler = (propName) => setBadStateObj(prev => ({
    ...prev,
    [propName]: prev[propName] || ''
  }));
  const updateHandler = (propName, propVal) => setBadStateObj(prev => ({
    ...prev,
    [propName]: propVal
  }));
  
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.entries(badStateObj).map(([k,v]) => (
        <div>
          Key: {k} &emsp; Value: {v} &emsp; &emsp;
          <button
            onClick={() => updateHandler(k, prompt(
              `Enter new value for ${k}`
            ))}
          >
            Update {k}
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
      <button
        onClick={() => clickHandler(prompt('Enter prop name'))}
      >
        Add new prop
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <h4>Demo showing the useState that I personally dislike</h4>
    <MyFunction />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Explanation**

- The `badStateObj` is initialized with only `id` and `name` props
- When user clicks the `Add new prop` button, a new prop may be added
- Separate buttons exist to update the value of each individual prop
- `clickHandler` adds the new prop entered by user with `''` value.
- `updateHandler` accepts `propName` and `propVal` as parameters and updates the appropriate props within the `badStateObj`.